# How to enable shell command completion for gcloud?

Tags: bash, shell, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to install the Google Cloud SDK on a Mac (following https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-mac-os-x), using the `install.sh` script:

```
~/Downloads$ ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh
```

In the logged output, I see the following instructions:

```
==> Source [/Users/kurtpeek/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc] in your profile to enable shell command completion for gcloud.
==> Source [/Users/kurtpeek/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc] in your profile to add the Google Cloud SDK command line tools to your $PATH.
```

Indeed, I find that using the `gsutil` command still leads to a `-bash: gsutil: command not found` error, so I still probably have to perform this step.

It is not entirely clear to me, however, what is meant by these instructions. I'm on a Mac and my bash profile is `~/.bash_profile`. What lines would I have to add in order to make the command line completion work?

**Update**

The first time I installed I did not use `sudo`. Reinstalling with `sudo`, I get an additional prompt whether to modify my bash profile, which upon accepting leads to the following lines added to my `.bash_profile`:

```
# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/kurtpeek/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/kurtpeek/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/path.bash.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/kurtpeek/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc' ]; then source '/Users/kurtpeek/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/completion.bash.inc'; fi
```

However, I still get `gsutil: command not found` errors.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `which gsutil`?

Comment: `which gsutil` yields no ouput...

Comment: For Ubuntu (20.04 LTS), I found a [few commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360580/how-to-get-shell-command-completion-autocomplete-for-gcloud/) which fixed my issues!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The trick was to run the `install.sh` using `sudo` as described in the update. After that I needed to restart the terminal (as described in the instructions) for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac Run below command to run the `install.sh` :

`sudo chmod +x install.sh`