# how to make gsutil autocompletion faster or disable autocompletion

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

when I type `gsutil cp [tab]`, it takes very long to show the list of files. In practice, it effectively hangs. How to disable autocompletion of gsutil or make it faster, please?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236580/how-to-enable-shell-command-completion-for-gcloud), autocompletion is accomplished by sourcing a shell-specific `.inc` file from one of your shell's profile or rc files. If on bash, this will be either .profile, .bash_profile, or .bashrc.  Commenting out or removing the line that sources this file will prevent it from being loaded when you start a new shell session.

As for why it hangs, you probably have a ton of objects in your specified bucket, or a ton of buckets in your configured default project. Gsutil has to perform a list API call under the hood when you do this, and because there is a max number of resources that can be returned in each paginated listing result, this can result in a lot of sequential HTTP requests, and thus a lot of time to finish.