# How to get shell command completion (autocomplete) for gcloud?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, autocomplete, ubuntu-20.04

I tried both 1. the official [Google installation for Ubuntu](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb), and 2. the one-liner `sudo snap install google-cloud-sdk --classic`, and neither didn't give me command autocompletion with <kbd>tab</kbd>.  Has anyone found a version of installation that gives you autocomplete?  I had it on my last laptop, so I know it's possible

ie. usage: `gcloud compute instances li` (here you hit <kbd>tab</kbd>) and it autocompletes to `gcloud compute instances list`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I successfully installed gcloud's Command Line Interface with autocomplete [here](https://vitux.com/install-google-cloud-sdk-on-ubuntu/) on February 24, 2021 at 7:00 P.M. EST (Eastern Standard Time).  My operating system is Ubuntu 20.04

Shell commands copied from the aforementioned source:

```
sudo apt-get update
# You should probably do other commands after this like
#   sudo apt-get upgrade, sudo apt-get dist-upgrade, 
#   but I didn't need them

# can cd wherever here:
cd
wget https://dl.google.com/dl/cloudsdk/channels/rapid/downloads/google-cloud-sdk-307.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
tar –xvzf google-cloud-sdk-307.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
cd google-cloud-sdk
./install.sh

# Answer a few "y/N" questions, mostly to your preference.
```

```
#   NOTE: Be sure to answer "Y" to the question "modify profile to update your $PATH and enable shell command completion?" !!  (This was the crux of the OP's question)
```

[image: This is an image description! (Obviously this image shows a bash session with the question about autocompletion)]

```
# Clean up:
cd ..
rm -f google-cloud-sdk-307.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

Comment: Check this link to the official documentation of [gcloud auto-complete](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/interactive-gcloud)

Answer (score 4):

The documentation says to source it in your profile. First, you will need to locate your `gcloud` installation. For me, it was in `/snap`. Then, locate the completions file (should be directly under the `` dir). For me, it was:
`/snap/google-cloud-cli/current/completion.bash.inc`
Last, update your profile. I am on bash so I did

```
cd
nano .profile
```

scroll to the end and add:
source /snap/google-cloud-cli/current/completion.bash.inc